# Delete file from a folder in symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-4.2

I have a controller with a supprimer action.

I can add files and delete them from the database.

As I followed the Symfony doc to create an uploader file, I also created in my services.yml this route

```
parameters:
 repertoire_soumissions: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/LettresSoumissios'
```

My problem

When I delete my file with my supprimer action, it's fine it deletes it in my database. But not in my folder /public/uploads/LettresSoumissions. I tried to find a way to be able to delete them in my folder too, but couldn't succeed it.

I tried also with a Filesystem() to remove them, but I've must have written it badly.

Here is my action in my controller class

```
/**
     * @Route("admin/soumission/{id}/supprimer", name="supprimer_soumission")
     */
    public function supprimerSoumission(Soumission $soumission, ObjectManager $manager){

        $lettresoumission= $soumission->getLettreSoumission();

        $filesystem = new Filesystem();

        $path='%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/LettresSoumissios/'.$lettresoumission;
        $filesystem->remove($path);
        $manager->remove($soumission);
        $manager->flush();
        $this->addFlash('success','Soumission supprimer !!');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('soumission');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Could it be due to a mispelling in the path name?

```
$path='%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/LettresSoumissioNs/'.$lettresoumission;
```

Missing a N letter.

Comment: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/LettresSoumissios/' is the path name, in my uploads folder i have LettresSoumissios folder

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this line:

```
$path='%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/LettresSoumissios/'.$lettresoumission;
```

The parameter above is simply a string with value:

> %kernel.project_dir%

You need a way to retrive the value of the parameter.

A clean way would be to inject the parameter value in the controller.

**Define your Controller as a service in your service.yaml:**

```
Namespace\NameOfTheController:
        arguments:
            - '%kernel.project_dir%'
        tags: [controller.service_arguments]
```

**Inject the value in the Constructor of your Controller:**

```
private $kernelRoot;

public function __construct(string $kernelRoot)
{
   $this->kernelRoot = $kernelRoot;
}
```

**Now change your code-line to:**

```
$path=$this->kernelRoot.'/public/uploads/LettresSoumissios/'.$lettresoumission;
```

---

to clarify:

You said:

> I also created in my services.yml this route

```
parameters:
 repertoire_soumissions: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/LettresSoumissios'
```

This is no service or route declaration, this is just a parameter => value mapping.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help!

Comment: repertoire_soumissions: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/LettresSoumissios' this instruction delete again the folder i dont want to remove the folde juste the file, how can i resolve this problem

Comment: Your path was `$path=$this->kernelRoot.'/public/uploads/LettresSoumissios/'.$lettresoumission;` so your filename is in the variable `$lettresoumission` delete path should be `$path=$this->kernelRoot.'/public/uploads/LettresSoumissios/'.$lettresoumission;` if not check your code ;)

Comment: you'r tottaly right brother, i hade a small error. Thank you again

Comment: Now you got it ;)